# How browser renders HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a structure similar to panels. This is what i have tried:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gg76pb1g/)

```
<div id='main'>
   <div id='firstp'>Panel 1</div>
   <div id='secondp'>Panel 2
      <div id='slide'>Panel 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and CSS is

```
#main{
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
#firstp{
   width: 20%;
   height: 100%;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   display: inline-block;
}
#secondp{
   width: 20%;
   height: 100%;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   background-color: red;
}
#slide{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid green;
   background-color: green;
}
```

I am curious to know how browser renders HTML while parsing. As we can see there are three panels, `Panel 3` being child of `Panel 2`, is seen on top of `Panel 2`. Whereas as per requirement , `Panel 2` should be on top of `Panel 3` and say when i click on some button in panel 2, panel 3 should slide behind panel 2 and comes forward on right side of panel 2. Hope i made myself clear. Please help.

Comment: Simple. When it reaches a closing tag, it knows it can render everything contained therein.

Comment: ok..but why not while rendering child elements of div should render below parent div?

Comment: Im not sure I follow your question

Comment: @RAKESHKUMAR — Because that would be silly. Children go inside parents (baring positioning rules that change that).

Comment: The parsing and rendering are a bit separate. I think your question is about rendering not parsing. For parsing XML, browser use libraries that use stacks. An open tag pushes to stack and a close one pops the dom element.  rendering is a far more complex thing

Comment: @Jamiec See as you said, `When it reaches a closing tag, it knows it can render everything`, so for any parent div having some child divs, first child div closing tag will occur, thus child div will render first and later parent div. In my case, parent div i.e. Panel 2 is appearing behind Panel 3, which is a child of Panel 2

Comment: Ah, ok now I understand your question. I dont know the answer.

Comment: @Braim rendering is complex and thus confusing to me...Can you please suggest some changes which will do the trick?

Comment: you don't need to worry about how rendering is implemented. You just need to fix your CSS. can you elaborate a bit on what should be look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want panel 2 to be on top of panel 3 then you will need to apply something like `z-index:-1;`.

I have modified your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gg76pb1g/16/) to show this working.

Panel 3 is behind panel 2 as you requested and there is a button that when clicked transforms the panel to the right. You can easily neaten this up to hide the entire panel and do some cool jQuery stuff to make the slide transition nicer.

Just try to remember that unless you say otherwise, children will usually appear in front of their parent.

Comment: Just a note..When i tried to give panel 2 a higher value of z-index than panel 3, then it doesnt work. Panel 3 comes on top of Panel 2.. See this http://jsfiddle.net/gg76pb1g/17/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't about browser rendering, it's your CSS that's making the children exceed the height of the parent.

Because you've fixed the height of the parent, yet you've said that `#slide` is 100% in height, but there's another child of `#secondp`, which is the text node `Panel 2`. So technically, `#secondp` has a height of `100% + height of Panel 2`, hence the overflow.

To remedy this, put the text node `Panel 2` inside an element, then set the height of that element (I've used 10%) and then adjust the height of `#slide` to be `100% - specified height of the new element`.

Here's an example:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gg76pb1g/6/)

HTML:

```
<div id='main'>
    <div id='firstp'>Panel 1</div>
    <div id='secondp'>
        <div id="slide1">Panel 2</div>
        <div id='slide'>Panel 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#firstp{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#secondp{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#slide1 {
    height: 10%;
}
```

You'll also notice I've added `vertical-align: top` to `firstp` aswell, otherwise it'll be off the top.

Also, I've added `box-sizing: border-box` to prevent the border overlapping the parent.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but my requirement is little different. Your shared fiddle doesnt depict the expected behavior. Sorry!

Answer (score -2):

```
#main{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#main>div{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
#main>div{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
#slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: What is this an answer to? You need, at very least, some text describing what your change is and how that change answers the question.

Comment: @shaik I guess you dint got the problem.